# Where to ask programming discussion questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, stackexchange

There are a number of stack exchanges:

- **Stack Overflow** for programming questions, algorithm and data structure implementations, and software development tools.
- **Programmers** for architecture, design, process and methodology, software project management, software licensing, and other "whiteboard" questions
- **Code Review** for best practices, security reviews, performance, correctness
  Software Quality Assurance for quality control, automation, and testing
- **Programming Puzzles and Code Golf** for different puzzles
- **Computer Science** for the mathematical and scientific foundations of computing

But in reality in "**Programmers**" if you ask a theoretical question (that requires discussion) it will be closed. This is strange as there are at least three other stack exchanges specifically for coding questions - making the existence of "Programmers" a bit of a mystery.

I'm going to try it now. I am going to ask a question that doesn't have an answer of

> DO A, THEN B, THEN C should be the result.

I'm expecting no answers except "I'm afraid I cannot do that Dave. Now I must close you".

So is there anywhere that I can go?

Answer (score 2):

Discussions are not suited for the Q&A portion of any Stack Exchange site. You may want to check out the chat rooms, though. Programmers has one that is pretty active - [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). Other sites may have others as well. For extended discussion on the Stack Exchange network, this is what is available. Otherwise, a site that is more like a discussion forum may be better suited.

Comment: Thanks, but The Whiteboard looks a bit of an unstructured mess. Is isn't even clear where people are asking questions, or answering them. Most of all, there appears to be no delineation by topic; which, if true, makes it a pointless place. To add to it there appears to be several hours between... replies.